# Как связать две записи в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть два типа записей : Страны и Города, соответственно в странах я добавляю новые страны, а в г->г. Мне нужно ,что-бы во время добавления города я мог выбрать страну(типа как категория). Может есть какой-то плагин?

Answer (score 0):

Помог плагин Advanced Custom Fields